# Unable to use scanner. Scanner detected by system but not by software. Live USB works perfectly but my installed destro could not find the drivers

Tags: drivers, printer, scanner

When I plug in my HP desktop Ink Advantage 3635 in my Debian stable it shows a notification that a printer has been connected but nothing happens after that. I open Xsane but it couldn't find the drivers needed for my printer. Same with skanlite.

[image: xsane error]

I tried booting my Lubuntu live USB drive and it picks up the scanner no problem. This is what it shows:

[image: from live drive]

I use Debian stable with xfce4

Comment: xUbuntu has supports for hardware that Debian hasn't. Maybe you need to try with                                Debian "non-free".

Comment: ok that could be it. So what do you  mean by debian non-free? Do you mean I should check the non free section of their website for drivers?

Comment: Debian is distributed in two "versions". Standard includes exclusively open-source; "non-free" includes some proprietary drivers.

Comment: i have the non free version of debian installed

Answer (score 0):

Had to install the following software from the debian's crappy [website](https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner):

- [hplip](https://packages.debian.org/buster/hplip)
- [libsane-hpaio](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libsane-hpaio)
- [libsane](https://packages.debian.org/libsane)

Reason? Well it's an All-In-One printer, scanner, girlfriend, etc. Therefor it requires separate drivers that Xsane cannot provide.